# List expansion in lift

Tags: javascript, scala, lift

I'm very new to working with lift, so please bear with me. If I want to implement something like https://help.squareup.com/ where the list items are hidden until the title is clicked. What's the best way to implement something like that in lift? Is there a widget I could use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery.. Like this (do not forget to attach the library itself)

```
$('.open_below').click(function(){
    $(this).next('div.info').slideToggle();
});
```

And HTML code (a small piece related to your question)

```
<div class='open_below'>Click me</div>
<div class='info' style='display:none;'>Put some information here</div>
```

Try it http://jsfiddle.net/3EbdN/